# Adapting wildcard characters to DBMS/Connections in .Net

Tags: .net, connection, wildcard, database

A developper in my company has developped a C# project containing classes to execute SQL queries on the following DBMS :

- **Access (A DB file with the extension ".mdb")** by using one of the following connections :

  - An **ODBC** connection.
  - An **OLE DB** connection
- **Access (A DB file with the extension ".accdb" extension)** by using one of the following connections :

  - An **ODBC** connection.
  - An **OLE DB** connection.
- **DB2** by using an ODBC connection.
- **MySQL** by using one of the following connections :

  - An **ADO .Net** connection.
  - An **ODBC** connection.
  - An **OLE DB** connection.
- **Oracle** by using one of the following connections :

  - An **ADO .Net** connection.
  - An **ODBC** connection.
  - An **OLE DB** connection.
- **PostgreSQL** by using one of the following connections :

  - An **ADO .Net** connection.
  - An **ODBC** connection.
- **SQL Server** by using one of the following connections :

  - An **ADO .Net** connection.
  - An **ODBC** connection.
  - An **OLE DB** connection.

I want to implement a method that will be used to adapt wildcard characters in a string used in a predicate of a SQL query.
Then the SQL query will be executed.
When a developper needs to use wildcard characters then he will use a known character independant from DBMS.

Wildcard characters can differ from DBMS.
Examples :

- The wildcard character used by Access is '*'.
- The wildcard character used by SQL Server is '%'.

But I wonder if the wildcard character also depends on the connection used to communicate with the DBMS.
The wildcard character used by an ODBC connection could be different from the wildcard character used by an ADO .Net connection.
I have not been able to perform a test on each pair of DBMS/Connection listed above because I cannot use some DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have executed programmatically select queries for each pair of (DBMS/Data provider) listed in my first post except for the pair (DB2/ODBC).
I have included a predicate in the where statement of my select query.
I have used the multi-character wildcard character : %
The wildcard character '%' works for each pair of (DBMS/Data provider) on which I have performed the test.